# AEM Campaign analytics

Tags: aem, personalization

We building personalization feature and use AEM targeting engine to deliver personalization content. However, I see that in admin section of the AEM Segmentation, there is any attribute called "Impresssions" which I believe is stats on how many times the customized content was shown to user.

Assuming that, how does AEM get to know the statistics? Is it something AEM takes care of automatically or I have code or configure something explicit. The reason why I ask is, I see the snippet like below in kernal.js file.

```
if (window.CQ_trackTeasersStats && n.trackingURL) {
    h(M, n.trackingURL)
}
```

I noticed that n.trackingURL is null in my case.

Any help shall be appreciated. And also should I looking for impression statistics in author env or publish env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AEM Campaign use a OOTB or custom Impressions service to calculate the Impressions.
There are two option in AEM to calculate the impressions

1. Yes, This something AEM can take care automatically
   for you but it will not give you a correct picture as every instance will be having a separate copy so you have to write some code to collect all values and push it back to all environment.
   [image]
2. You also have an option of using your Adobe Sitecatalyst to
   calculate an impression which gives you a more accurate count of
   impressions. for this sitecatalyst expose their rest service so that
   you can update the impressions on run time.

n.trackingURL is null because you have not configured the sitecatalyst account for this environment.

[Read docs](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/personalization/campaigns.html) Or 
[Implementations instruction:](http://www.wemblog.com/2014/11/how-to-use-impression-service-in-cqaem.html)